# Запись данных в SQLite. orm sugar

Tags: java, android, orm, retrofit

Получают с сервера `json` в котором хранится 18 тыс. записей. При выполнении метода  onResponse , приложение зависает. Использую `orm sugar`, `retrofit`

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<List<ModelJoke>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {    
    List < ModelJoke > list=response.body();

    for (ModelJoke ob:list)
    {
        jokes=new dbJokes(ob.id,ob.cid,ob.value);
        jokes.save();
    }

    mProgressDialog.dismiss();    
}
```

После завершения записи, приложение опять работает. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Пишете в БД в основном потоке

Comment: метод выполняется в основном потоке. вынесите его второстепенный

Answer (score 0):

Я пробовал использовать ваш вариант сохранения, работало через одно место
Попробуйте использовать SugarRecord.saveInTx(). У меня всё прекрасно с ним работает.